# Javascript closures and onload

Tags: javascript, closures

I am learning to use closures, and I'm not sure about what is the best approach for my situation. I edited my code for clarity and it contains dummy code. I have to access to the `handleCannon` function if the user clicks on the `test` element. If I declare `handleCannon` within the `onload` event it won't work. If I declare both functions outside of the `onload` event the `handlebullet` function won't be able to get the `test1` element because it's not loaded yet. Would the following code be acceptable? What is the best way to do this?

```
let handleCannon;

window.onload = function() {

    handleCannon = (function(el) {
        return function(el) {
            el.innerHTML = "bananas";
            handleBullet.reset();
        }
    })();

    let handleBullet = (function() {

        let test1 = document.getElementsByClassName("test1")[0];
        let rect = test1.getBoundingClientRect();

        console.log(rect);

        return {
            reset: function(){
                console.log("reset");
            },
        }

    })();

}
```

and the body contains:

```
<div class="test" onclick="handleCannon(this)"></div>

<div class="test1"></div>
```

Comment: why us an inline event handler which forces you to use a global?

Comment: you mean I should use something like "function name() { ... }" rather than "let name = (function() { ... })();" and declare them out of the onload event?

Comment: not sure why you are using the function that return a function for `handleCannon`

Comment: no, you should be using addEventListener to bind the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using inline attribute handlers (which are hard to manage and generally considered to be pretty poor practice), attach the handler using Javascipt instead, inside the `onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const test = document.querySelector('.test');
  // handleCannon:
  test.addEventListener('click', () => {
    test.textContent = 'bananas';
    handleBullet.reset();
  });
  // ...
```

Note that assigning to `onload` will mean that this handler will be overwritten if anything else assigns to `onload` (similarly, another handler already on `onload` when this script runs will be overwritten) - you might consider using `addEventListener` instead, allowing your scripts to listen for the `load` event in multiple places, which can be useful with larger or multiple scripts:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const test = document.querySelector('.test');
  // handleCannon:
  test.addEventListener('click', () => {
    test.textContent = 'bananas';
    handleBullet.reset();
  });
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement this code. So using "window.addEventListener('load', () => {..." would allow me to add code to the onload event from multiple .js files?

Comment: I tried to separate the handleCannon and handleBullet in two different .js files and add them with window.addEventListener but of course handleCannon can't access handleBullet now. Do I have to keep these two in the same file? I was trying to tidy up my code by keeping stuff separated.

Comment: The only way for two separate scripts to communicate is through *something* global. Either use a global, or use a module bundler instead, like webpack.

Comment: Just to keep my code tidy and readable, is it acceptable to declare globals? I mean, I can keep all in the same file, but soon it would became a monster to mantain.

Comment: Right, that's why for any seriously sized project, it's best to use a module bundler.

Comment: I'll look that up. Thanks again.